# Why does Swift not convert this Int array literal to the correct type?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, types

I've been working through some problems on Leetcode and brushing up on my Swift and ran into this strange error.

The code below:

```
 // Definition for a binary tree node.
 public class TreeNode {
     public var val: Int
     public var left: TreeNode?
     public var right: TreeNode?
     public init(_ val: Int) {
         self.val = val
         self.left = nil
         self.right = nil
     }
 }

class Solution {
    func inorderTraversal(_ root: TreeNode?) -> [Int] {
        guard let root = root else {
            return []
        }

        if root.left == nil && root.right == nil {
           return [root.val]
        } else {
            return inorderTraversal(root.left) + [root.val] + inorderTraversal(root.right)
        }
    }
}
```

Namely, if I try to concatenate the arrays in one line as above, I get an error `'Int' is not convertible to '[Int]'`.

However, if I create a separate variable called `middle` for the middle value, and use that instead of `[root.val]`, it works as intended with no errors.

It seems that Swift somehow does not have enough information to know that `[root.val]` is an Int array in certain contexts. Why is this?

Comment: I tried it my end and it worked fine for me, without any error.

Comment: What version of Xcode/Swift are you using?

Comment: I can confirm behaviour in XC 9.2 Playground.

Comment: It works in Xcode 9.3.1 (Swift 4.1), so they've apparently addressed the problem.

Comment: I tried it in Xcode 9.0, so I got the same error.

Comment: This was in the Leetcode online environment. The only context they give is that "Compatible with swift 4.0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to go with Swift compiler issue on this one. I can't back this up with any evidence, but by hinting to the Swift compiler a little more the issue goes away.